# Probability to pick last four pages

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

A $125-$pages document is on the floor randomly spread. If $4$ pages are picked up at random, what is the chance that these are the document's last four pages and in the right order? Page $122, 123, 124$ and $125.$

Comment: See: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2128980/chance-of-selecting-the-last-k-pages-in-correct-order-from-a-set-of-n-pages/2128999#2128999

Comment: What do you mean "about" 4 pages ? And what have you tried ? On this site, you need to first show some effort ..